# TFF: 'trainable=True ' causes decrinsing of accuracy

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I work with TFF, here is a part of my code :

```
def create_keras_model():
    
    baseModel = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor=tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

    for layer in baseModel.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    return model
```

With this model I find test-accuracy value = `0.8`
Now, I would like to change `layer.trainable = True`, but the test-accuracy value decrease to `0.2` and loss becomes `12` . which is not normal, can anyone tell why.